# Syslog full of "Access denied for user"

Tags: mysql, linux

I have full syslog of this message:

mysqld[963]: 2016-10-23 20:54:14 140708269390592 [Warning] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I would like stop spamming syslog.

Please how can I find which process are trying connect to mysqld.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Show us a couple of line before and after this line

Comment: Before and after this line is same thing:                                                     Oct 24 20:17:57 serverName mysqld[26659]: 2016-10-24 20:17:57 140660724669184 [Warning] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Oct 24 20:17:57 serverName mysqld[26659]: 2016-10-24 20:17:57 140660724972288 [Warning] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Oct 24 20:17:57 serverName mysqld[26659]: 2016-10-24 20:17:57 140660777401088 [Warning] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 2):

you can use **Netstat** which is a command-line tool that displays network connections (both incoming and outgoing).

Comment: I try use Netstat but I dont see something helpfull... Can you please advice how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an app allowed to connect to that database then reconfigure the driver to use a different port (and of course change the port of the MySQL server).

And it's actually a general rule to not run the MySQL on the default port (if you are). I had to allow remote connections to the database but it caused dozens of attempts per day so decided to use "random" port and since the change my mysqls logs are empty.

Comment: I close mysql port with iptables but problem still there. It seems to be some local process...